# How to call bunch of python executable files mentioned in .txt file from one script

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a python script e.g. startTesting.py which is under "C:\python\Trigger" folder. This folder has one list.txt file which keeps a list of executable python files( under another folder). I am pointing to this list.txt file in my startTesting.py script so that all mentioned test files in list.txt will get executed.

Test files are kept under another folder "C:\python\Executable"

My python code is not accessing the python scripts under Executable folder.

List.txt looks like :

```
../Executable/testscript1.py

../Executable/testscript2.py
```

And my startTesting.py looks like:

```
>>> import os

>>> test_case_list = "List.txt"

>>> os.system('python %s' %test_case_list)
```

But when tried to execute the file, I got this error :

```
File "List.txt", line 1

../Testware/testscript.py
^
```

Any guess to overcome this problem is welcomed!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the scripts contained in the file, read the file:

```
with open('List.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        execfile(line.strip())
```

What you're doing now is running `List.txt`, which isn't going to work too well.

Comment: Hi,I tried and got this error: >>> with open('List.txt', 'r') as handle:
...     for line in handle:
...             execfile(line)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Executable/testscript.py\n'
>>>

Comment: @user2033758: Whoops, sorry. Forgot to strip out the newlines. Try it now.

Comment: I made it work with the example you have given and here how it worked: 
test_case_list = 'list.txt'

testfile = open(test_case_list,'r')
    lines = testfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        os.system('python %s' % line)